# Get infomation from Compressed XML file in Android application

Tags: android, xml, https, gzip

I have a compressed(.gz) xml file on my server. I need to read that file and get the information to store in the SQLite DB

Have to access the server via HTTPS.

"https://SERVER_ADDRESS/PATH/employee.gz"

Normally when I log in to the server to the folder where these xml files are stored, it asks me for user name and password. So in code how to handle this.

I searched but didn't get the exact one I need. Great if someone Can help me in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are reading from HTTPS, GZIPInputStream might work. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html

Also, look at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/auth/UsernamePasswordCredentials.html for accessing password protected directories with http.

Comment: Was this helpful? If not, can you clarify the question a bit more? Otherwise, +1! ;)

Comment: went through these. But still didn't resolve the problem. I need to get an input stream from (https://SERVER_ADDRESS/PATH/employee.gz) gzipped file. This is HTTPS and Normally when I access to this folder which is in server I have to provide username and the password to acces this folder to access the gz file.